# Docker Environment variables not passing to Vue App

Tags: docker, vue.js

I am trying to containerize a Vue JS app.  I am placing my API root into an environment variable, but whenever I try to write the variable value to console, it comes out blank.

The following is my docker-compose file.  See the "env_file" entry at the bottom.  This references ".env.development" which is at the same level as the docker-compose file.

```
version: '3.4'

services:
    my.ui:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myui
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    logging:
       options:
          max-file: "10"
          max-size: "25m"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    env_file: 
      - .env.development
```

Then I have the following entry inside the .env.development file:

```
VUE_APP_URL="http://localhost:61554"
```

Then I have the following in my javascript:

```
console.log("API URL: " + process.env.VUE_APP_URL);
```

This is just logging an empty string.  So I can't make any API calls.

It's driving me crazy.  Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong in terms of configuring the environment variables on the Vue app?

Comment: What is the content of your Dockerfile?

Comment: @kickinchicken can you try configuring your application with `dotenv` .This can help you load the variables from the .env file into your application's environment during the build process. this might help you [dotenv with vue.js](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/lessons/environment-variables/1/)